# Sum of angular momentum of all electrons in a magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

Can the sum of angular momentum of all rotating electrons in all the aligned atoms in a permanent magnet have a significant contribution to the macro angular momentum of the magnet? If yes, why does it not behave like a spinning top , like, resisting a change in its orientation?

Comment: Why do you think it *doesn't* behave that way? Ever heard of Larmor precession? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect